# Crash on AppStore Connect - NO_CRASH_STACK but not shown in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift

We've crash reports from App Store connect but they are not reflecting in the Firebase Crashlytics. We've gotten ahold of one of the crash logs from the Organiser crash repot window but its with very little information.

Following is the crash report.

[image]

```
Incident Identifier: 2487F67A-D4B6-435D-A8A4-B93DE1F0AC34
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,6
Process:             Vrinda Project [2938]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/62CD732F-7C3E-4C3F-B182-67D7A4802456/Vrinda Project.app/Vrinda Project
Identifier:          com.Vrinda Project.Vrinda Project
Version:             03 (4.1.0)
AppStoreTools:       12E506
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,6:13
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.Vrinda Project.Vrinda Project [881]
Date/Time:           2021-08-03 04:12:49.7920 +0200
Launch Time:         2021-08-03 04:12:48.7273 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.6 (18F72)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.04.01
Report Version:      104
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001ab68aacc
Triggered by Thread:  0
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001ab68aacc _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 1532 (AssertCommon.swift:132)
1   Vrinda Project                  0x0000000104ed5d38 AppDelegate.loadUserData() + 1252664 (AppDelegate.swift:0)
2   Vrinda Project                  0x0000000104ed3d98 AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 1244568 (AppDelegate.swift:211)
3   Vrinda Project                  0x0000000104ed4220 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 1245728 (<compiler-generated>:0)
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa4e07a8 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 360 (UIApplication.m:2279)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa4e223c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3504 (UIApplication.m:2671)
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa4e8388 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1244 (UIApplication.m:4201)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9b3bc98 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 152 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:436)
8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa0a4f58 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 104 (_UISceneLifecycleState.m:109)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9b3c830 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 224 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:549)
10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9b3c2f0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 484 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:501)
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9b3c640 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 768 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:548)
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9b3be7c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 340 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:454)
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9b443c0 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... + 196 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:72)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9fb2970 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 892 (BSAnimationSettings+UIKit.m:50)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa0bdd68 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 276 (_UISceneSettingsDiffAction.m:23)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9b440b8 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 384 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:57)
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a996bfa0 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 776 (UIScene.m:1419)
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a996a920 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 256 (UIScene.m:1140)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a996bbc8 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 248 (UIScene.m:1386)
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa4e6528 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 572 (UIApplication.m:3697)
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9fdbfd0 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 388 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:45)
22  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b70885d8 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 440 (FBSScene.m:435)
23  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b70b3d44 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.200 + 128 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:365)
24  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b70976a4 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240 (FBSWorkspace.m:355)
25  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b70b3a0c __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 372 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:364)
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a76e381c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a76e730c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 268 (queue.c:468)
28  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b70dbfa0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48 (FBSSerialQueue.m:184)
29  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b70dbc30 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 448 (FBSSerialQueue.m:227)
30  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b70dc184 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32 (FBSSerialQueue.m:258)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7a709e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1967)
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7a708e4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208 (CFRunLoop.c:2011)
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7a6fbe8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268 (CFRunLoop.c:2048)
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7a69bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 820 (CFRunLoop.c:2925)
35  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7a69360 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
36  GraphicsServices                0x00000001bf0a7734 0x1bf0a4000 + 14132
37  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa4e4584 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3269)
38  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa4e9df4 UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4740)
39  Vrinda Project                  0x0000000104dadd70 main + 40304 (AppDelegate.swift:23)
40  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a7725cf8 start + 4
```

Following is the first method called in App Delegate for loading user data:

```
func loadUserData() {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: kSignedInUser) as? Data {
            do {
                guard let userData = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? UserDataModel else {
                    return
                }
                signedInUserData = userData
                signedInUser = userData.user
                if let location = userData.confirmedLocation {
                    confirmedLocation = location
                }
                return
            } catch {
                fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't encode data: \(error)")
            }
        } else if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kGuestConfirmedLocation) as? Data {
            do {
                guard let location = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? CityModel else {
                    return
                }
                confirmedLocation = location
                return
            } catch {
                fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't encode data: \(error)")
            }
        }
        defaultLocation = VrindaProjectManager().getDefaultLocation()
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it one of the two `fatalError`?

Comment: Did not understood `fatalError` means?

Comment: `fatalError` kills the app, it terminates it. So isn't one of the two`fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't encode data: \(error)")` that is called, and make the app crash? In XCode/Organizer, do it points you to a more specific line?

Comment: Did this crash occurred in the debug mode?

Comment: @Larme - The crash does not take to any specific line. Only the the method name `func loadUserData() {`

Comment: @WideAngleTechnology No. Its production crash issue. Not in Debug.

Comment: Do you understand that if `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData()` throws an error, `fatalError` will crash your app? You have to find why, we can't guess as we don't see the error message.

Comment: What is a guy named 'VrindaProjectManager'?  Where does it come from?